# Android Toolbar style

Tags: android, styles, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I've added a `Toolbar` to my Lollipop project. However, I'm having trouble styling the `Toolbar`. My title in the `Toolbar` appears to have a bold font, but I'd like it to be italic. Any idea how to achieve this? I've tried playing around with the `actionbar-style`, no luck.

I've set a style on the `Toolbar` with `app:theme="@style/toolbar"` and my `@style/toolbar` (parent `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`) is where I'm playing around with no good results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `TextView` inside Toolbar, for example :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Cool. Should be possible to style this without having to add a custom view, don't you think?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? Do not get warnings? "Element TextView is not allowed here"

Comment: @DarkLeonhart I was using Android studio.

Comment: I ended up using this, as I also needed a custom font on the title.

Answer (score 12):

The ToolBar title is stylable. Any customization you make has to be made in the theme. I'll give you an example.

**Toolbar layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle.Event"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />
```

**Styles:**

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ToolBarStyle.Base"/>

<style name="ToolBarStyle.Base" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle.Event" parent="ToolBarStyle">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!--Any text styling can be done here-->
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/event_title_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your Toolbar layout there. Is that in it's own file called toolbar.xml stored in the values folder...or what? Can you specify where this code is going?

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent a frustratingly long amount of time trying different variations of themes and styles to try and get my toolbar text to be white, "normal" font weight and have a white back button. This solution does seem long winded for such a trivial task but it's the only one that worked for me so thank you.

Comment: This is quite a convoluted answer with all the inheritance going on. Is it needed? you did not explain it.  How can we do something simple such as changing the text color or background color?

Answer (score 11):

This is actually really easy. There's a method on Toolbar called setTitleTextAppearance() that everyone seems to be overlooking. Just define your custom textAppearance in styles.xml, such as:

```
    <style name="MyTitleTextApperance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and then in your code, you just call :

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyTitleTextApperance);
```

and voila!

Comment: This doesn't work for `textStyle` (bold, italic) specified in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem mentioned above only occurs in Lollipop versions and not in Kitkat and lower versions. Lollipop does not follow the text style and put its own `TitleTextAppearance`. So even you add your own `TextView` child for your `Toolbar` (shown below), the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` will still override your styles.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/someToolbarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

To finally solve this, put your own `TextView` for the title and override the `setTitle` methods of the `Toolbar` to skip the Lollipop's predefined `TitleTextAppearance`.

```
public class YourCustomToolbar extends Toolbar {

    public YourCustomToolbar (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public YourCustomToolbar (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public YourCustomToolbar (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
     }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int title) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you then map the java class to your XML layout, please? Do you inflate the custom layout in all constructors? Also, do you wrap the layout in `<merge>`?

And my last question, do you then use it by putting `<your.package. YourCustomToolbar/>` to your activity's layout, or do you use `<include>`?

Comment: I edited your post and added `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"` to the TextView. This way, its base look is the same as the normal AppBar title appearance.

Answer (score -5):

You can apply a theme to the toolbar as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Just modify the style in your styles.xml, changing the `TextAppearance` attribute, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've tried creating my custom style as i said in the question, but no luck. Can you show me an example style that should work?